# Need a DataType which store data as Int, but also Decimal

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench, sqldatatypes

i've got stuck with something about datatypes in mysql

i have the following table:

```
id (int,primary key),
tipo (varchar(45)),
inteiro_pedaco (varchar(45)),
marca (varchar(45)),
a (decimal(11,1),
b (decimal(11,1),
c (int (11))
```

the A and B column should store data with the following format: 00.0, 00.1, etc.

But, A and B column should also be able to store data as if it was INT, not only decimal, however, if i try to put "10" for example, it automaticaly gets formated to "10.0"

The biggest problem is: those two columns (A and B) HAS to store 10 as value and other times 10.0, even if 10.0 is equal to 10, it has to be stored exactly the way it was sent, with or without the decimal. If the input was 10, it has to be stored as 10, if it was 10.0, it has to be 10.0

And i know that may sounds weird, but believe me, it will receive data as 10.0 sometimes, i wasn't using the 10.0 as example, it will REALLY receive data as 10.0 and 10

I tried reading about datatypes, but i could find none who fufil those requirements, except varchar, but i cant use varchar in this case, also, i cant make two separetely colunms to store the data, they gotta be in the same column

I was thinking about saving everything as decimal, and them formating it when doing a select, but in that case, i would have to make a new colunm just to store if it is decimal or not

So, there is any kinda of datatype who fits in the description above? If not, is formating the only way to do what i want?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Your data seems very confused.  Either the value is a number, and the trailing zeros don't matter.  Or the value is a string, and arithmetic doesn't really make sense.  What does the value contain?

Comment: Try float Data type

Comment: only numbers will be stored, however, neither i like this way of storing data, unfortunally, i dont have much of a choice because i just follow what people tell me to do. I gotta say, i suck at math, my boss tried to explain to me why this had to be this way, but i didnt get it at all, and he doesnt understand much of programming (in my case, i still learning, im just a trainee), so i tought i could try to check if it was possible, but by what it looks like, i think ill have to get in touch with my boss again and see what we will do, and try to explain him why this isn't possible

Comment: @saravanatn, i tried float, but it didnt worked, also, when typing big numbers, it turned into a mess, when i inputed 1234567890.0 it was saved as a completely different number

Comment: I didn't know there's any difference between `10` and `10.0`?

Comment: @dnoeth when the data is stored as 10, it will be used into a specific math calculus, whoever, when it is stored as 10.0, the "10" will also be used into a math calculus with range from 0 to 9. I suggested to my boss using another column but i was told to do everything into a single column (even thou i was against it because i also believed it wont work), so here i am now, trying to find an way to work around it, i think my last option is  to treat the data when doing the select

Comment: @Kouhei: If you got rules when it's supposed to be an INT or DECIMAL or whatever, you can use `CASE tipo WHEN ...`. But this will return only a single datatype (either INT or DEC) and the to get what you want there must be a casti as a VarChar with a matching format. Or you create a view where you split the data into multiple columns.

Comment: @dnoeth, retrieving only a single data type is a problem, too bad there isnt a datatype which acts as varchar and can be used for math calculus, but ill try a different approach, instead of working with the database, i think ill just store everything as decimal and treat the data at php itself

Answer (score 0):

If trailing or leading variables are important, then you should store the vaue as a string.  You really do not have much choice.

Basically, the value is not a number, it is some sort of code.  In the world of numbers, `10.0` is equal to `10`.

EDIT:

Based on your comment, you should have two columns that are both integers.  One is for "the part *before* the decimal point" the second is for the range.

You are making a mistake by trying to put two things in one column.

Comment: if storing as a string, when needed to do some math operations, wont be there some kinda of problem? puting it on a simple way, the number after the dot will be used in two ways, which is defined by the "tipo" colunm. The first way is: the number before the dot will be applied into some calculation and the number after the dot will define its range. The second way, when the "tipo" colunm does not match a specified condition, the entire number will be used for a calculation, even the number after the dot

Comment: @Kouhei . . . The string value will be (silently) converted to a number for the operation.  But you seem to have other problems.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider having multiple columns.  eg DEC_VAL, INT_VAL, STR_VAL

This will solve join issues and filter issues but is slightly harder to maintain.

Comment: it dont solve the problem because i cant have more than 3 colums for dimensions. A, B and C are used for almost everything. When "tipo" colunm is "tubo" for example, "A" will be external diameter and "B" internal diameter, but in case "tipo" column is "placa", "A" will be width and "B" thickness

Comment: because i cant figure out how to solve this problem, i came here looking for help and maybe a solution. in case i cant find an way out, i think ill just have to set up a meeting with my boss

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the problem is when you get the data as opposed to how it's stored, if the decimal point is throwing things off (like you want a certain appearance during output) maybe try a case statement for the select.

```
select case when cast(cast(A as int) as decimal) = A then cast(A as int) else A end
```

What we are doing here is testing if column A as an int is equal to column A as a decimal, and if they are the same we are casting it as an int. If they are not equal we leave column A as a decimal.

As the others noted this is kind of an odd problem, because most things will evaluate 1.0 = 1, but I'm guessing this is formatting for the output as opposed to a logical evaluation down the line. Anyway hope this helps :)

Comment: This will not work as CASE returns a single datatype, in this case a DECIMAL.

Comment: if i understood correctly, it wouldn't work, because if for example A have 10.0 stored and is tested as int (10) if it is equal to A as decimal, it would be understood as true, right? then the output would be 10, but the .0 cant be ignored, well... i dont say i said something stupid (im still learning, so, forgive me hehe)